# Rails 5.1.4 ::How to query a MySql Database for testing?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am relatively new to Ruby on Rails and I am trying to build a robust system with plenty of wonderful tests. I am currently trying to run a test on my database queries but I am having an error when I run the query.

Disclaimer -> I know that this query is a bit messy, but I am more familiar with SQL queries and this was the best method for me.

```
def setup
    @parts = Part.find_by_sql("SELECT DISTINCT num AS Part_Number,description AS Description, QTYONHAND as On_Hand, QTYONORDER as On_Order,
    QTYALLOCATED as Allocated, QTYNOTAVAILABLETOPICK as Not_Avail_Pick FROM (part JOIN qtyinventorytotals ON part.id = qtyinventorytotals.PARTID) WHERE part.id in
    (SELECT PARTID FROM qtyinventorytotals);").to_a
  end
```

This is just the setup function for the test case and the error is:

```
Run options: --seed 34672

# Running:

E

Error:
PartTest#test_parts_pull_from_db:
ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation: Mysql2::Error: Field 'activeFlag' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO `part` (`id`) VALUES (980190962)



bin/rails test test/models/part_test.rb:11



Finished in 7.505619s, 0.1332 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.
1 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

Here is my database.yml file with the database. I am running a local MySql and querying from the localhost.

```
# MySQL. Versions 5.1.10 and up are supported.
#
# Install the MySQL driver
#   gem install mysql2
#
# Ensure the MySQL gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'mysql2'
#
# And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
#   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/old-client.html
#
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: root
  password: root
  host: localhost

development:
  <<: *default
  database: xxxxxxxx

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: xxxxxxxx
  username: root
  password: root

# As with config/secrets.yml, you never want to store sensitive information,
# like your database password, in your source code. If your source code is
# ever seen by anyone, they now have access to your database.
#
# Instead, provide the password as a unix environment variable when you boot
# the app. Read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database
# for a full rundown on how to provide these environment variables in a
# production deployment.
#
# On Heroku and other platform providers, you may have a full connection URL
# available as an environment variable. For example:
#
#   DATABASE_URL="mysql2://myuser:mypass@localhost/somedatabase"
#
# You can use this database configuration with:
#
#   production:
#     url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
#
production:
  <<: *default
  database: xxxxxxxx
  username: root
  password: root
```

Again, I am new to Ruby on Rails and all of the wonderful Ruby Magic that happens. I have a feeling that the error is in the database.yml file but I haven't found any resources to steer my in the right direction. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated so that I can really get testing.

Also, I am only reading from this database and there will be no writing, updating or deleting.

EDIT:

Here is the full test class:

```
require 'test_helper'

    class PartTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
      def setup
        @parts = Part.find_by_sql("SELECT DISTINCT num AS Part_Number,description AS Description, QTYONHAND as On_Hand, QTYONORDER as On_Order,
        QTYALLOCATED as Allocated, QTYNOTAVAILABLETOPICK as Not_Avail_Pick FROM (part JOIN qtyinventorytotals ON part.id = qtyinventorytotals.PARTID) WHERE part.id in
        (SELECT PARTID FROM qtyinventorytotals);").to_a
      end

      # ActiveRecord will return a nil object if there is an error with the DB pull.
      test "parts_pull_from_db" do
        assert_not @parts.nil?
      end
    end
```

**New**
When I run this query in the console, the result is

```
Part Load (21549.0ms)  SELECT DISTINCT num AS Part_Number,description AS Description, QTYONHAND as On_Hand, QTYONORDER as On_Order,
    QTYALLOCATED as Allocated, QTYNOTAVAILABLETOPICK as Not_Avail_Pick FROM (part JOIN qtyinventorytotals ON part.id = qtyinventorytotals.PARTID) WHERE part.id in
    (SELECT PARTID FROM qtyinventorytotals);
=> [#<Part id: nil>, #<Part id: nil>, #<Part id: nil>, #<Part id: nil>, #<Part id: nil>, #<Part id: nil>, #<Part id: nil>, #<Part id: nil>, #<Part id: nil>, #<Part id: nil>, #<Part id: nil
>, #<Part id: nil>, #<Part id: nil>, ...]
```

When I run the rails server, the application successfully pulls the data from the database and renders the data nicely.  Why am I getting these results when running from the rails console or the testing environment and not from running the application?

Comment: Do you have fixtures? they could be generating the error

Comment: No fixtures here

Comment: Post the test?.

Comment: I'll get the test up. It fails regardless of the condition of the assert, i.e. if assert TRUE will still throw an error. I'll get the script up though.

Comment: and when you run that SELECT statement directly in MySQL's console program, does it create the same error? ergo not a Ruby problem?